# NumberFormatter() - pad with a specific number of spaces possible?

Tags: swift, string-formatting, number-formatting

I am trying to use NumberFormatter() to create a string representation of CGFloats. Ideally, I would like to create a signed string like transforming a value of

`10.1` -> `"  10.1"` and

`-10.1` -> `"- 10.1"`, the integer part being padded with spaces.

This is the closest I have gotten, but it pads the integer portion with "0" so I get

`10.1` -> `" 010.1"` and

`-10.1` to `"-010.1"`

If I don't use `.minimumIntegerDigits` there is no padding.

I'm using a monospaced font to display the values and I'm trying to make sure they don't get jiggly as they change, and I was just hoping there would be some way to use a space in place of the 0 but otherwise exactly how `.minimumIntegerDigits` works.

```
extension CGFloat {
   func signedPaddedString() -> String {
      let formatter = NumberFormatter()
      formatter.positivePrefix = " "
      formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 3
      formatter.paddingCharacter = " "
      formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
      formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
      return formatter.string(from: self as NSNumber)!
   }
}
```

Comment: Worst case scenario, if the API wasn't designed to support this, you could just turn off the minus sign, and glue it on yourself after the formatting.

Comment: Well, I tried commenting out the `.positivePrefix` so it's just the number being worked on, but it still just fills 0's and `.paddingCharacter = " "` does nothing obvious in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the `positiveFormat` and `negativeFormat`
properties, which are format patterns according to the [Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-numbers.html#Number_Format_Patterns):

```
extension FloatingPoint {
    func signedPaddedString() -> String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.positiveFormat = " * ##0.0"
        formatter.negativeFormat = "-* ##0.0"
        return formatter.string(for: self)!
    }
}

print((10.1).signedPaddedString())    // "  10.1"
print((-10.1).signedPaddedString())   // "- 10.1"
print((123.45).signedPaddedString())  // " 123.4"
print((-123.45).signedPaddedString()) // "-123.4"
print((0).signedPaddedString())       // "   0.0"
print((-1).signedPaddedString())      // "-  1.0"
```

If you want to suppress localization (e.g. in [countries using decimal comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Countries_using_decimal_comma)) then add

```
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

Comment: Interesting... I noticed that after setting `.positiveFormat` & `.negativeFormat` as you suggested, that setting a `.paddingCharacter` now works as expected, as does `.paddingPosition = .afterPrefix/.beforePrefix` Many thanks!

Comment: can this also work as an extension for FloatingPoint? I tried it and used `return formatter.string(for: self)! as! Self` but it just gives errors about not being able to cast from type Swift.string to Swift.float etc.

Comment: @Martin R this will create a new `NumberFormatter` every time you call this property. It would be better to create a static formatter extending Formatter `extension Formatter {
    static let signedPadded: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.positiveFormat = "* ###0.0"
        formatter.negativeFormat = "-* ##0.0"
        return formatter
    }()
}
extension Numeric {
   var signedPadded: String { Formatter.signedPadded.string(for: self) ?? "" }
}`

Comment: @Paul check my comment above on how to extend `Numeric` protocol instead of `CGFloat` type. Btw no need to create a method, a computed property will suffice.

Comment: @Paul: Making it an extension for FloatingPoint should just work (see update). – As Leo suggested, you may want to create the formatter only once, for performance reasons.

Comment: @LeoDabus: An extension on Numeric (or FloatingPoint) bears the danger of a crash at runtime: A custom type may conform to that protocol, but NumberFormatter cannot handle it.

Comment: @MartinR I am not forcing unwrapping the result. In that case it would probably fail silently. My intention extending `Numeric` was to make it work with `Decimal` type as well.

Comment: @LeoDabus very helpful. The idea of using a method was to make parameters for the number of integer digits and decimal places.